# VHDL Vivado's behavioral simulation returns unknown (red X) over output assignment operation

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

I have written this simple process. It's supposed to accumulate ((b-a)/n)*yi terms, where yi is an input that is updated per every clock cycle, and then output the result of the sum.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 
entity Integrator is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           n : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           yi : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           start : in std_logic;
           clk : in std_logic;
           output : out signed (15 downto 0);
           done : out STD_LOGIC);
end Integrator;

architecture Integrator_arch of Integrator is
signal do : std_logic;
signal i : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, res : signed(15 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk='1') then
            if(start='1') then
                do <= '1';
                i <= (others=>'0');
                done <= '0';
                res <= (others=>'0');
            elsif(do='1' and done='0') then   
                if(i=unsigned(n)) then
                    output <= res;
                    do <= '0';
                    done <= '1';
                else                    
                    tmp1 <= resize(signed(b)-signed(a),16);
                    tmp2 <= resize(tmp1/signed(n),16);
                    tmp3 <= resize(tmp2*signed(yi),16);
                    res <= res + tmp3;
                    i <= i+1;
                end if;
            end if;  
        end if;         
    end process;
end Integrator_arch;
```

And this is the testbench:

```
architecture Behavioral of Integrator_Testbench is
signal start : std_logic;
signal clk, done : std_logic;
signal yi : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal O : signed(15 downto 0);
begin
    uut: entity work.integrator(integrator_arch)
            port map(a=>"11111110", b=>"00000010", n=>"00000100", yi=>yi
                ,start=>start, clk=>clk, done=>done, output=>O);
    process
    begin
        clk<='0';
        start<='1';
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='1';
        wait for 200ns;
        
        start<='0';
        clk<='0';
        yi<=x"0003";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='1';
        yi<=x"0003";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='0';
        yi<=x"0001";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='1';
        yi<=x"0001";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='0';
        yi<=x"0000";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='1';
        yi<=x"0000";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='0';
        yi<=x"0002";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='1';
        yi<=x"0002";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='0';
        yi<=x"0000";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='1';
        yi<=x"0000";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='0';
        yi<=x"0000";
        wait for 200ns;
        
        clk<='1';
        yi<=x"0000";
        wait for 200ns;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

But here's the problem, the output is always reported as unknown (red Xs) when I run a behavioral simulation. What's more weird is that it runs completely fine in a debug session, and by running a line-by-line debug session I was able to get the correct output, which is x"0006"!!!

[image: Result of behavioral simulation]

After two hours of attempting to find the issue, I finally decided to ask. Specially since it runs completely fine and outputs the correct result in a line-by-line debug so I have no idea why the simulation keeps acting out.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Look inside the integrator process and see where it goes wrong.  That's basic debugging. Also in general when you see XXXX, check you aren't driving the signal from 2 places, like the testbench and the component itself. But the initial UUUUs suggest that's not the case here.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Unfortunately the debugger works perfectly fine and the output shows the correct solution, which only puzzles me more on why the simulation fails. As for the driving the signal, I only drive the output signal once throughout the entire code so that isn't the issue.

Comment: So you're saying if you add tmp1-3 and res to the waveform window they are all correct before the clock edge producing the final output? Could you add them to the sim image in the question?

Comment: I would declare the temp1-3 and res as variables instead of signal.

Comment: @vipin why? Then the pipeline length would match the n input.

Comment: Brian knows of which he comments (he's likely run your testbench with all of Integrator's internal signals in the simulation waveform already). The x"XXXX" on o (output) comes from res when done goes high. `res <= res + tmp3;` here res is x"UUUU"and when added to tmp3 (x"0002") yields x"XXXX".   You'll find that tmp1, tmp2 and tmp3 want to be initialized where res is, where start is evaluated as'1', serving as a synchronous reset. You're evaluating done in Integrator which requires -2008. There's also a sequence issue assigning res from res + tmp3 before done. output is x"0000.

Comment: The [bottom waveforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwhlR.jpg) show the result of initializing tmp1 - tmp3. You can also see output doesn't reflect res + tmp3.

Comment: (You can also see why vipin mentions using variables. Your debug session may be making invalid assumptions.) (And that's not a simple process as noted by the ability to introduce errors.)

Comment: You'd also find that the ability to use the "/" multiplying operator in Xilinx synthesis is limited to powers of 2 (ug901) which is the same thing as shifting right, yet you use n as a length 16 signed value.

Comment: actually `res` is correctly initialised : however it has lost its correctness as a result of other pipeline errors before the `done` state. I don't know how you are debugging it : clearly not correctly. You might thank @user1155120 for providing the simulation results : they do, as I suspected, expose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer by more trial and error

It seems that the result of one line of `numeric_std` expression takes one clock cycle to settle down, so when I tried to make it more readable by writing

```
tmp1 <= resize(signed(b)-signed(a),16);
tmp2 <= resize(tmp1/signed(n),16);
tmp3 <= resize(tmp2*signed(yi),16);
res <= res + tmp3;
```

It took 4 clock cycles to settle down and before these 4 clock cycles are done, the port is set to unknown.
So I shortened all of those lines into one line

```
res <= res + resize((resize(b-a,16)/signed(n))*yi,16);
```

And now the result is ready for me in 1 clock cycle just as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your start signal should be asserted longer. At the beginning of the simulation tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 are uninitialized and it takes 3 clock cycles to have a properly calculated tmp3 value (because you use the <= signal assignment within a clocked process). If at the start of the simulation your start signal is asserted only one cycle, on the cycle following its deassertion res is accumulated with an still uninitialized tmp3 value and therefore give an unknown res.

Solution:

- at the beginning, assert start 3 more cycles,
- or initialized tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 during the declaration
- or initialized them together with res when start = 1

You could change your code for tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 variables. signals in a clocked process behave like a pipeline. It's only a question of whether it's a behavioral or synthesizable code, whether it meets the timing constraint or not. VHDL is a description language ; there is no single good answer fom the functional point of view.